# Combining two queries into one view

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have this table:

TABLE S_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT      S_REGION        D_TABLE     D_COLUMN    D_TEXT  
1           1           1               Table1      Column1                 
2           1           1               Table1      Column1     Hello
3           2           2               Table1      Column1     
4           2           2               Table1      Column1     Hallo
5           3           3               Table1      Column1     
6           3           3               Table1      Column1     Hi
```

Then I have this view to remove all history doublets:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `VHS_TEXT`
AS SELECT 
`S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT`, 
`S_TEXT`.`S_REGION`, 
`S_TEXT`.`D_TABLE`, 
`S_TEXT`.`D_COLUMN`, 
`S_TEXT`.`D_TEXT`
 FROM 
`S_TEXT` LEFT JOIN 
`S_TEXT` AS `t2`
ON (
`S_TEXT`.`S_TEXT` = `t2`.`S_TEXT` AND `S_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT` < `t2`.`PS_TEXT`
)
WHERE
`t2`.`PS_TEXT` IS NULL;
```

VIEW VHS_TEXT:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT      S_REGION        D_TABLE     D_COLUMN    D_TEXT  
2           1           1               Table1      Column1     Hello
4           2           2               Table1      Column1     Hallo
6           3           3               Table1      Column1     Hi
```

Then I have this query to show if more recent changes have been made in REGION 2:

```
SELECT `VHS_TEXT`.*, (CASE WHEN k.`PS_TEXT` > `VHS_TEXT`.`PS_TEXT` THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS `CHANGED`
FROM `VHS_TEXT` LEFT JOIN 
`VHS_TEXT` AS k
ON 
(
`VHS_TEXT`.`D_TABLE` = k.`D_TABLE` 
AND `VHS_TEXT`.`D_COLUMN` = k.`D_COLUMN`
AND k.`S_REGION` = 2
)
```

Result:

```
PS_TEXT     S_TEXT      S_REGION        D_TABLE     D_COLUMN    D_TEXT  CHANGED
2           1           1               Table1      Column1     Hello   2
4           2           2               Table1      Column1     Hallo   0
6           3           3               Table1      Column1     Hi      0
```

I would like to build the query into the view VHS_TEXT itself to get the samme result of the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `VHS_TEXT`;
```

Comment: Create a second view that does this.

Comment: I want to combine the two queries into one view. Making two views on top of each other is same as having a query on top of first view.

Comment: You can use `UNION` [Try this](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union.php)

Comment: Please show me :-)

Comment: A UNION gives a strange result.